# Set of support strategy

Tags: logic

I'm having trouble understanding the set of support strategy,and i was asked to solve the following problem:
Using the supporting sets strategies prove that the following deductions take place:
$$q\wedge r\to p,\;p\vee q,\;q\to r\vdash p$$
I tried looking on the internet for help and managed to find a short youtube video,but it did not help with this specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhWslFWaFzE) tutorial will help,
it's like prove by contradiction:
$$\color{red}{q\wedge r\to p},\color{orange}{\;p\vee q},\color{blue}{\;q\to r}\vdash p\tag*{Assume $\neg p$}$$
\begin{align}
&\color{orange}{\;p\vee q},\boxed{\neg p}\vdash q\tag*{Conditional equiv&Modus ponens}\\
&\color{blue}{\;q\to r},q\vdash r\tag*{Modus ponens}\\
&\color{red}{q\wedge r\to p},q,r\vdash \boxed{p}\tag*{Conjunction Intro&Modus ponens}\\
&\boxed{\neg p},\boxed{p}\vdash\bot\tag*{$\bot$ Intro}\\
\end{align}